# Exterior Powers of finite abelian group

Tags: finite-groups, multilinear-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module (i.e., a finite abelian group). My question is: for what $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{n\geq 2}$ the map 
\begin{align}
\alpha_{n}:\bigwedge^nA&\to A^{\otimes n}\\
a_1\wedge \cdots \wedge a_n&\mapsto \sum_{\pi\in \mathbb{S}_n}(sig(\pi))a_{\pi(1)}\otimes \cdots\otimes a_{\pi(n)}
\end{align}
 is injective? For $n=2$,  $\alpha_2$ is injective. It follows, for example, just by induction on $r$, if $A=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}m_1\oplus \cdots \oplus\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{m_r}$.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't like to write $\sum_{\pi}(-1)^{\pi}a_{\pi(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes a_{\pi(n)}$? ; )